# How to add a default text to appear in all the rows of one specific Gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have added a Gridview, and I have connected it to a Database. I save an integer as the primary key. When retrieving the primary key I want to add a default text to the front of it. I was hoping if there is any way in which I can set the particular set of cells in the Gridview to have the text I want as default.

This is how it appears :

[image]

I want it to appear as follows :

[image]

Here's my code :

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
           &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div style="overflow:auto; height: 175px; width: 900px;">

            <asp:GridView ID="grdNDA" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Font-Size="Small" Width="95%">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NDA ID" DataField="NDA_ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company Name" DataField="COMPANY_NAME" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country Incorperated" DataField="COUNTRY" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Created" DataField="DATE_CREATED" />
                     </Columns>

                     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                         <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                         <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of showing the screenshot, better add the relevant code.

Comment: Use `TemplateField` to add custom column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DataFormatString` property like:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="NDA ID" DataField="NDA_ID" DataFormatString="SL/NDA/{0}" />
```

For more complex scenarios consider using `TemplateField` instead of `DataBound`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NDA ID" SortExpression="NDA_ID">
  <ItemTemplate>
    SL/NDA/<asp:Literal runat="server" Mode="Encode" Text='<%# Eval("NDA_ID") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```